# MemoryError in numpy normalization

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am working on a large dataset consisting images.

When I run the following code:

```
data=[]
def image_to_feature_vector(image, size=(128, 128)):
   return cv2.resize(image, size).flatten()

for i in range(0,len(imagePath)):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath[i])
    features = image_to_feature_vector(image)
    data.append(features)

data = np.array(data) / 255.0
```

I got an error as:

> np.array(data) / 255.0
>
> MemoryError

How to fix this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Let me guess, 32bit build of Python?

Comment: @DanMašek No, I am using 64bit build version.

Answer (score 2):

Some easy memory saving strategies include

1 preallocate `data` and avoid creating a temporary list

```
data = np.empty((len(imagePath),) + features_shape)
for i, slc in enumerate(data):
     ...
     slc[...] = features
```

2 use in-place operations where possible

```
data /= 255.0
```